# Liferay LDAP Sync portal.ext configuration

Tags: tomcat, ldap, liferay, tomcat8, liferay-7

My OS is CentOS7.

I unzipped bundle with Liferay7-tomcat8, created database on Postgresql (DROP/Create public schema ofc).

Start Portal with startup.sh script, configured admin account and database settings, after this made shutdown.sh.

By [this advise](https://web.liferay.com/web/nelson.aguayo/blog/-/blogs/recommendations-for-your-portal-ext-properties) rename portal-setup-wizard.properties to portal-ext.properties and add this LDAP settings:

```
ldap.auth.enabled=true
ldah.import.enabled=true
ldap.import.method=user
ldap.import.on.startup=true
ldap.import.interval=10
ldap.export.enabled=false

ldap.base.provider.url=ldap://xxx.example.org:xxx
ldap.base.dn=dc=example,dc=xxx
ldap.security.principal=uid=username,ou=Domain
ldap.security.credentials=********
ldap.auth.method=bind
ldap.users.dn=cn=users,dc=example,dc=xxx
ldap.user.mappings=screenName=sAMAccountNamen\npassword=unicodePwd\nemailAddress=mail\nfirstName=givenName\nlastName=sn\nfullName=cn\ngroup=memberOf
ldap.password.policy.enabled=true
ldab.auth.search.filter=(&amp;(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=@screen_name@))
ldap.import.user.search.filter=(&amp;(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=*)(mail=*))
ldap.groups.dn=OU=Groups_X,OU=_Groups,OU=_Example
ldap.import.group.search.filter=(objectClass=group)
ldap.group.mappings=groupName=cn\ndescription=description\nuser=member

ldap.error.password.age=age
ldap.error.password.expired=expired
ldap.error.password.history=history
ldap.error.password.not.changeable=not allowed to change
ldap.error.password.syntax=syntax
ldap.error.password.trivial=trivial
ldap.error.user.lockout=retry limit
```

And, when i'm starting Liferay portal by startup.sh script, i can read in log (catalina.out) that all works fine, that portal-ext.properties is loading, nothing errors, or warnings. But in portal settings nothing changes.

No users from LDAP, no groups, no LDAP settings.

What am i doing wrong?

EDIT: When i tryed to configure LDAP sync by portal Console GUI, all works fine, but in this instrument i cann't choose ldap.groups.dn to import. I reinstalled Liferay several times, trying with portal-setup-wizard and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In previous versions of Liferay Portal, system scoped settings for LDAP were set in the portal.properties file and modified using a portal-ext.properties file. But with Liferay 7/DXP, those settings must now be made via System Settings.

If you need to change any of these options, navigate to Control Panel → Configuration → System Settings. Go to the Foundation section and find the entries with LDAP in the title.

check

> https://dev.liferay.com/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/7-0/ldap

This property are no longer available in portal.properties as well.

> https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html#LDAP

[image]

[image]

Comment: But System settings LDAP don't have options to different users and groups dn. I have needed groups in 3 ou, and users in 1 cn.

Comment: check uploaded screenshot, there's options to put this groups in system setting. add same as your portal-ext.properties ldap.groups.dn=OU=Groups_X,OU=_Groups,OU=_Example

Comment: Thx, friend! You save me! They must make BIG banner with this information and guide to configure LDAP in System, not instance settings -_-

Comment: So, summary. Now, i do all step by step (most from official manual):

1. Made Instance settings. 
2. Made System Settings in LDAP servers settings. Save it
3. Restart server.

And after this, i check System Settings LDAP servers settings and see that all were reseted to default.

Comment: This is very unsual, not sure if you did reset to default on System setting. Saving instance setting shouldnt reset system setting,. Can you reconfigure and check? It can be bug in liferay as well.

Comment: Do this again and again. Instance settings doesn't resets. And System settings showing right until i make shutdown.sh/startup.sh. After started, i open system settings > foundation > ldap servers and see that all reseted to defaults.

In system settings i made LDAP server with same ID and same name as instance LDAP server have